# Ошибка в консоли при запуске Sublime

Tags: github, консоль, sublime-text-3

Вот такая ошибка появляется при каждом запуске Sublime:

> shell_cmd: bin\go get -x -u github.com/DamnWidget/godef
>   golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru github.com/fatih/motion
>   github.com/josharian/impl github.com/nsf/gocode
>   github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc gopkg.in/alecthomas/gometalinter.v1] [dir:
>   D:\Программирование\Технологии\Python\Основы Python] [path: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Download\Files;D:\Download\Files\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\Download\Files\Library\usr\bin;D:\Download\Files\Library\bin;D:\Download\Files\Scripts;D:\Programming\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;D:\Microsoft
>   VS Code\bin;C:\Users\admin\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2019.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.3.3\bin;;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\SUBLIM~1\Packages\python-pywin32\st3_windows_x64\pywin32_system32]

Чем это может быть вызвано?

Comment: Почему вопрос про python, если там `go get`?

Comment: @hedgehogues, честно говоря я новичок в программировании и как мне казалось, что дело именно в нём. Если вы знаете, как решить проблему буду рад вас выслушать )

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это ошибка? Сам ST работает? Где появляется этот текст?